# Beginner Python user Boolean Query

Tags: python

CodeAcademy's Python course is running me through loop functions and I don't understand an outcome. The goal is to see if a list is a mirror of the other list. i.e. [1,2,3] to [3,2,1]

After 20 minutes I looked at the solution and I don't understand why this does not return True every time?:

```
def reversed_list(lst1, lst2):
  for index in range(len(lst1)):
    if lst1[index] != lst2[len(lst2)-1-index]:
      return False
  return True
```

The "return True" is indented to the same level as "for index", which would override any value returned from the prior line.

Alternatively, when I introduce an "else" at the "if" indentation, everything returns True:

```
def reversed_list(lst1, lst2):
  for index in range(len(lst1)):
    if lst1[index] != lst2[len(lst2)-1-index]:
      return False
    else:
      return True
```

Can anyone help a noob?

Comment: You need to understand that each function can only `return` *once*. In your second case, as long as the first iteration didn't satisfy that it will immediately return `True`, all subsequent iteration *will not run*. In the first function, only if every iteration statisfied the condition will `True` be returned, else it can never get to that line.

Answer (score 1):

The `return False` causes the function to exit completely while returning False, so the `return True` line is never reached in that case. Placing an early return statement is a way of interrupting function execution

Answer (score 0):

If your statement `if lst1[index] != lst2[len(lst2)-1-index]` statement finds any items that do not match, our function will end right at that moment. No more code will be executed.

When you add that else statement, it means that if there are any items that do match, the function will return True and no more code will be executed.

Answer (score 0):

The first and the second code you proposed give different outputs.
And you should know that functions can use `return` only once.

What helps is to print out intermediate results.

1

```
def reversed_list(lst1, lst2):
  for index in range(len(lst1)):
    print(index)

    if lst1[index] != lst2[len(lst2)-1-index]:
      print('False')
      return False

  print('True')
  return True
```

2

```
def reversed_list(lst1, lst2):
  for index in range(len(lst1)):
    print(index)

    if lst1[index] != lst2[len(lst2)-1-index]:
      print('False')
      return False
    else:
      print('True')
      return True
```

Run my code with the added lines that prints you intermediate results. You will see that the second function will only iterate over the first element and then return either `True` or `False`.

Answer (score 0):

In the first case `return True` is the end of your function. You have to iterate through the whole `range(len(lst1))` in order to reach it. So if the condition of the `if`in the loop is matched, the `return False` statement is executed and the function ends there.

In your second case, you never iterate through the whole list. At the first iteration, you check the condition `lst1[index] != lst2[len(lst2)-1-index]` where `index = 0` and return a True or a False.